# Request for TeX.SE pamphlet

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

Can we please have a pamphlet for TeX.SE, too?

[English.SE pamphlet](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2155/12903)

Comment: Which group would be the key target?

Comment: @JosephWright: Well, I thought about placing some at the local university. I would assume that there are some people using TeX and therefore might be interested in TeX.SE.

Comment: The ones who never experienced _the Joys of LaTeX_? :)

Comment: When I wrote TeX, I wanted to say TeX, LaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeTeX,...

Comment: I really like this idea.

Comment: The first thing that I noticed was bad line justification in the English.SE pamphlet.

Comment: I think this would be a great idea - I'd love to put up a poster in my department advertising the site.  However, as the English one is so *awful*, let's jump the gun (shark?) and make our own.  Maybe we could collect ideas in the answers below?  (PS to any SE employees, the English pamphlet isn't *so* bad, but it also doesn't quite leap out at you and say "Visit this site!".)

Comment: We could offer typesetting these as a service to other SE...

Comment: I don't see the point very much. Is this to print and put on the walls of our workplaces? To send as an attachment in our mails to our coworkers, friends, etc? To share in our social networks? To put in our blogs? However, if you think it could be a good way of promoting the site, go for it! :)

Comment: By the way, if the idea is to promote TeX.SE, maybe it would be nice to show a screen capture of a common/tricky question, along with its answer, conveniently tuned to the poster format, rather than showing a bunch of text and some web links. We could have several different posters with different questions-answers, and at the very bottom of each poster a sentence like "Find out more at tex.stackexchange.com". Our product are questions and answers, so why not show our product in the poster, and also show the people how this site works?

Comment: Although I'm generally skeptical of the whole poster idea, if we are to make one, I really like Julian's idea of having multiple posters each with a different question.

Comment: I think I liked the idea but I thought the pamplet didn't look nice (no offence). I think an A4 (or equivalent) size poster would be a nicer idea and would appeal more to the eye. We should have enough experience in this forum to hack something together. All we need is agree on the content and then have somebody implement the poster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making a pamphlet for this site could be useful, if you have ideas for what you want to do with it. We made the English one mostly as a way to promote our academic programs, and to give the [SE Ambassadors](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/are-you-an-english-student-or-teacher-do-you-want-some-free-food) something to hand out to the people in their group. It wasn't very hard to make - you can use these section guidelines as a jumping off point if you want to make one yourselves:

- Brief summary of the site (e.g. This is a free, community driven Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems...)
- Example questions
- Why should I use this site?

Obviously feel free to change the layout around, or redesign it however you'd like.